# Redirected You too Many Times and Homepage Not Loading

Tags: redirect, hacked

Thanks for the support.

The WordPress site apparently was hacked... I did find 2 FTP files that the kacker was trying to use to increase FTP quota in the root folder, which I deleted. I also replaced all WordPress files, except the "wp-content" folder.

Right now, other pages of the site are loading except the homepage. Each time I tried to access the homepage, I get the error, "this page isn’t working... redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS."

1- I cleared the browser history several times, setting it to "All Time".

2- I ran WordPress folders and files permission through SSH to make sure it's not a folder and file permission issue.

3- I Ran a database repair through SSH, which was completed successfully.

4- I deactivated all plugins

5- Cleaned up .htaccess file

But, when I tried to use WordPress Repair Tool, I get the error message that I have to add "define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);" to the "wp-config.php" file, which I already added before trying to run the URL, for example, "https://mydomainname.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php". At this point, I'm guessing WordPress is not able to read the "wp-config.php" file that's why I'm also getting that error when I try to call the repair line from the "wp-config.php" file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check for  any malicious code in wp-config.php and other files
simple open your wp-content/ and delete the following folder or file that you have not installed or have a name in the wrong format like
if it is a real file then it will have a name like wp-config.php
if it is miraculous then its name looks like w84$set.PHP

Comment: I checked "wp-config.php" to see if there is any code that is not supposed to be there, but everything looks OK. I'm not sure why WordPress is not able to read the "wp-config.php" file or the allow repair code that I added to "wp-config.php" file. Screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/A2YD27RXk3f_